# Trying to add fake click ul li item via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events, client-side

I am trying to add a fake click unordered list list item.

I have a a ul li list item:

```
<ul>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Suppliers New", "SupplierPartialViewNew", "Supplier", null, new { @class = "navLinks", id = "ManageSuppliersNew" })</li>
</ul>
```

I want Ul that has list item which has id `ManageSuppliersNew` will clicked automatically or on his own.

I am trying with this code, but not able to do so:

```
 var item = document.getElementsByClassName("#ManageSuppliersNew");
 item.click();
```

I am getting error:

> "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'click'"

Can some one tell me how do I make a fake click on client side on .cshtml page which is already loaded all the list items.

Comment: @I would be very happy if you would answer the same question other than editing the question prof.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because `item` is undefined due to your use of an `id` selector in the argument of `getElementsByClassName`.

You should use `getElementById()` along with the id value (minus the `#` prefix), or `querySelector()` (with the `#` prefix). Either of the below examples will work for you:

```js
var item = document.getElementById('ManageSuppliersNew');
item.click();
```

```js
var item = document.querySelector('#ManageSuppliersNew');
item.click();
```

Comment: Hey I tried that too.. its coming null with # or without #

Answer (score 0):

```js
var item = document.getElementById("#ManageSuppliersNew");
 item.click();
```

"ManageSuppliersNew" is the id of the element.
You have to use getElementById selector.

Comment: Just FYI it's `getElementById`, no `s` and lowercase `d` and there shouldn't be a `#` in the argument.